# Why Android foreground service stops when I manually disable the location in Andriod settings?

Tags: android, service, location, foreground-service

I have written a foreground service in my app and I am doing some API operation every 5 minutes once. My app is mainly used for location tracking and it always needs location permission. If user disable the location for my app by any chance then I just want to create a local notification from my service. My app users mostly don't bring my app to foreground. So I want to check whether the location permission is enabled or not. If not then I just want to show a notification which tells the user that the app needs location permission. Now I just manually went to android settings and disabled the location permission for my app. I have two services running in my app. Suddenly both stopped working. I just want to know the reason why it stopped? Will it be stopped always until I enable the permission? What can I do to intimate my user to enable the permission? As my app always runs in background, I want to handle it in service. Please give your opinion to solve my issue.

Comment: there should be some `Exception` in log after `Service` crash

Answer (score 0):

NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field'LanguageInitBean$Data LanguageInitBean.data' on a null object reference

When I change the storage permission, I can't read the data stored in memory

Ask for help

```
public static class LanguageInitCache{
    public static LanguageInitBean languageInitBean;
}
private void startToNext(String response) {
    languageInitBean = GsonUtils.json2Bean(response, LanguageInitBean.class);
}
```